# Where did the tradition of new releases on Christmas Day start?

Tags: open-source, history, ruby

Perl 6 is being released on [Christmas Day this year](https://twitter.com/obra/status/651564829946220544). I'm familiar with Ruby having a history of releases on Christmas Day, going back as far as [Ruby 1.0 in 1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Early_releases) if not further. However, a quick scan of the Wikipedia article on [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) doesn't seem to indicate any previous Christmas Day releases.

Did the tradition of new releases on Christmas day start with Ruby, or have other programming language implementations, or other open source projects, had releases on that day prior to Ruby doing so?

Comment: Early development of Perl6 was extremely optimistic, and it was believed to be done by Christmas (2001). That date slipped, so … next Christmas? During the next couple of years, it was a running gag that Perl6 would be done by Christmas – the remaining question was which year, if ever. That seems to be settled now, and I'll doubt they'll miss their release data: the Rakudo\* distribution has been usable for many years.